# correlation in statsmodel using python

Tags: python-2.7, statsmodels

could u please help me to Find correlation for these two lists importing stats-model in python.

```
  a=[1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0]
  b=[789.0,786.0,788.0,785.0]
```

using some built-in functions

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,2.0])
>>> b = np.array([789.0,786.0,788.0,785.0])
>>> np.corrcoef(a,b)
array([[ 1.       , -0.2236068],
       [-0.2236068,  1.       ]])
```

Just use indexing to extract the right one:

```
np.corrcoef(a,b)[0,1]
```

Comment: when i dont use this numpy and find correlation i get c = [1] 0.223608, how can i get the similar output using numpy

Comment: I edited the answer, but really you should be doing minimal work on your own. This is trivial.